# Retransmission of all TCP packets Android Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, tcp

I have two android 4.03 devices that communicate using sockets. The application works fine, but sometimes the client try to connect (Socket.connect()) to the server and I get the SocketTimeOutException that I set to 2500ms. The devices are in a local Network so in the normal cases the server responses in few milliseconds. I check the connection with WireShark and I saw that the only packet that is sent is the first SYN. After that nothing. 
Since the second SYN packet (retrasmission of SYN) is sent after 3 seconds by default, I tried to rise up the socket timeout to 4 seconds (setSoTimeout(4000)) and the application always works!
**Why the server socket doesn't reply to the first SYN?**

After that, I tried to sniff a normal communication to see what normally happens. Every single packet in the communication is retransmitted! I attached a screenshot of my wireshark capture. What does it mean?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

**EDIT:** 
The router doesn't forward the packet and drop it without any reply. I tried the following code that doesn't work sometimes.

```
public static Socket connect2(InetSocketAddress sa, int SOTimeout)
        throws SocketTimeoutException, IOException {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        // dummy packet to cause the ARP cache of the router to update
        socket.connect(sa, 20);
        Log.d("NICO", " CONNECTION GONE BY DUMMY PACKET!");
        return socket;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.d("NICO", "TCP Socket Dummy Packet gone");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException();
    }
    int i = 0;
    int t = 1000;
    boolean finish = false;
    while (!finish) {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.connect(sa, t);
            Log.d("NICO", " CONNECTION GONE!");
            return socket;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            Log.d("NICO", " ANOTHER CONNECTION!");
            if (finish)
                throw new SocketTimeoutException();
            i++;
            if (i * t > SOTimeout) {
                t = i * t - SOTimeout;
                finish = true;
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    throw new SocketTimeoutException();
}
```

The router drops also the other packets..
It doesn't depend from the ARP table, because it is correctly inserted in the router..

Comment: Are you sniffing on multiple interfaces ? Also, are the packets totally identical ? Don't forget to check below the IP layer.

Comment: Is it possible that it depends by the router instead?

Comment: I am using the sniffing tool of the router and then I filtered the captured file setting the interested ip and port. Now I check if the packets are identical!

Comment: If the capture comes from the router, the duplicates might be just the routing, i.e the packet received by the router, and then the same routed outgoing packet. It would be a normal behavior. The router MAC address will appear in both packets (one as source and one as dest) if it is the case. About the real problem, can you Wireshark on the server to see if SYN is received ? That would eliminate transmission problems.

Comment: Agree to ElderBug. Getting the first packet dropped in a new stream is generally possible and expected with many routers. But for every packet, a big no-no.

Comment: I checked the packets by comparing the bytes and they are identical. The mac address in src and dst field are both set to 00:00:00:00:00:00 in every sniffed packet

Comment: Going to analyze the server.. It could be long because it doesn't occur at every time (but often). 
@joe it can occurs but for me it's strange that it occurs so often

Comment: You Cannot have packets in the network with src and dst MAC being all zeros. Strange. Something is terribly wrong somewhere. Check the way you are dumping the packets and make sure you are following the right approach.

Comment: @joe I would not worry about that. The router is probably sniffing at IP level and don't fill MAC addresses (but in reality they are not 0s). Also, dropping the first packet is not normal, if it were it would be a huge problem on the Internet.

Comment: I sniffed in the router and also in the server for a single session. I haven't replicate the situation of the the first SYN's loss. By the way, the capture file on the server hasn't the duplicate packets! The router capture file is always the same (with wireshark's black duplicate packets). So probably @ElderBug you are on right, and the duplicate packets are only because I m sniffing on the router: server doesn't reply with double packets! Now the question is: why SYN packet is lost so frequently?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the problem. By the way, by analyzing the capture on the router in which the SYN isn't re transmitted, I notice that there is only one SYN, WITHOUT the second one in the black row. Could it means that the packet wasn't forwarded?

Comment: That would indeed be the router's fault. Is the problem more frequent after some inactivity ? If you can, try another router, or temporarily replace the router with a switch. You should still check if SYN is received on the server, to be sure.

Comment: Here I am! I replicated the problem! Sniffing in the server side the SYN doesn't arrive at all! So it's a router fail! The problem seems happen after some inactivity of my application! There are more hosts connected to the router and they have Internet access so the routers is never inactive. 
For what concerns my client software I think to set the SO time to 500ms after that retry a new connect() for 5 times..Is a good idea in your opinion?

Comment: The problem certainly has to do with ARP. If the router has no ARP entry for the server, it will send an ARP request on first packet but drop it. What you said should work, if you are sure the server will connect in 500ms. You could also send a dummy packet to the server just before connecting (maybe waiting 10ms). It can be anything (TCP, ping, UDP ...) as long as it is sent to the server IP. A better router can probably do the trick too :)

Comment: Your solution is probably better if your real environment has some traffic to the server, because then the link will stay active and the SYN will never be dropped.

Comment: Edit: problem not resolved and updated my ask...